# Application windows change size and position on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

I upgraded to Windows 10 on the 29th on my laptop and I'm pretty much OK with everything except the new window management that's been put in place. I don't know if anyone here noticed, but applications that I've become used to and have worked up until now on Windows, [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/WinSplit-Revolution.shtml) for window tiling and [AllSnap](http://ivanheckman.com/allsnap/) for window snapping no longer work. I'm guessing it's because the new "Snap" feature that's been introduced, but this "Snap" doesn't come close to what WinSplit Revolution offered.

I'd be OK with these two applications not working. I can arrange windows manually (although the lack of window to window snapping, which AllSnap provided up until now, is annoying) and up until now they would stay in place, but in Windows 10 something changed. Now the windows randomly change position and size. For example when I place Firefox window to take up roughly 75% of the left section of the screen, if any of the following things happen:

- I put the laptop to sleep
- I close and reopen the application
- I maximize and then minimize the application window

[This right here happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Wvd.png). Notice that the **window is moved ever so slightly from the bottom left corner of the screen**. It happens randomly and I don't know why. Sometimes the application window takes up only 50% of the window. In either case I have to manually reposition and resize them every time this happens.

I tried turning off this new "Snap" in settings, but it didn't help. I really like Windows 10, and what could make it even better if there was some toggle, some option that would turn on the old window management, like it was up until Windows 8.1, where previously mentioned programs worked and application windows stayed in placed. At the very least can you tell me if the same is happening to you, or am I just going insane?

Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior you described with WinSplit Revolution in Windows 10.  Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. I have a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2, which has a SUPER high-resolution screen. Whenever I would close the lid and then open it, all of the windows would move to a different location. There are several of us having this issue here:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-W-Series-Laptops/Windows-10-Open-Windows-Are-Resized-When-The-Lid-Is-Closed/m-p/2146376/highlight/true#M52609

The way we got around it is from steevcoco's response above.

```
In the Display Settings, I set the scaling slider to 100%.

In the advanced settings, I clicked Set A Custom Scaling Level; and I set THIS to 150%.
```

You will probably want to check out your original values. For me, the "Display Settings scaling slider" was originally at 150% and "Custom Scaling level" was 100%. So the solution for me was to switch them. If you have any "Display Settings scaling", set it to 100% and make that same scaling using the "Custom Scaling level" instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just tested everything suggested by you and others in the thread that you linked but it didn't do the trick. Windows are still behaving the same. I had all the settings on 100%. If I put custom scaling to 150, everything becomes large and I can't really use the desktop, as this is a 15" laptop with 1366x768 resolution (taskbar takes up quite a chuck of the screen for example). I fear this might be working as intended, so I'm starting to get used to it.